# Related if conditions controled with && operator

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have an if control as following ;

```
if (Directory.Exists(System.IO.Path.Combine(systemPath, "Reports", companyName))
    && Directory.GetFiles(System.IO.Path.Combine(systemPath, "Reports", companyName),
       "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Length > 0)
```

First part of control checks whether directory is exists and the second part is for controlling number of the files in directory.

Since the directory may not be exists, the second part it can give an exception of **DirectoryNotFoundException**. Also I don't want to make nested if conditions (first if for directory, second if for counting the files)

My question is that;

Does "&&" operator checks the second condition although the first condition is not satisfied ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it doesn't see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> The conditional-AND operator (&&) performs a logical-AND of its bool
>   operands, **but only evaluates its second operand if necessary.**

Answer (score 1):

As soon as one condition is false, the checking will be aborted. However, you will either have to use nested if's or use a try-catch-block for DirectoryNotFoundException. Besides, you will add readibility and you can react towards the directory not exisiting.

Answer (score 1):

The `&&` operator is called a *lazy* operator, since it will only evaluate (left-to-right) what is needed to come to a conclusion. The non-lazy counterpart is `&`. The same holds for `||` and `|`.

```
void Test()
{
    bool r;
    r = F() && T();     // Prints "False", returns false
    r = T() && F();     // Prints "True False", returns false

    r = F() & T();      // Prints "False True", returns false
}

bool F()
{ Console.Write("False "); return false; }

bool T()
{ Console.Write("True "); return true; }
```